# C++, Too many initializer values, Bool Array Initialization using DMA Pointers

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, list-initialization

I don't understand why am i getting this error. Is it not the correct way of array initialization?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool **arr = new bool *[5]; //rows
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new bool[5]; //col
    }
    arr[5][5] = {
        {false,true,false,true,true},
        {false,true,false,true,true},
        {false,true,false,true,true},
        {false,true,false,true,true},
        {false,true,false,true,true},

                    };
    
}
```

Comment: It's just not possible to assign to pointers or arrays like that. You need to initialize the elements one by one.

Comment: You'll also have a much easier time in C++ if you get used to using `std::vector` and company *now* rather than later. `bool**` is the stuff of nightmares and will be difficult to effectively free when done, let alone copy or reference if needed.

Comment: Instead of array, use `vector<vector<bool>>`.

Comment: You can only use brace initialization during initialization and unfortunately initialization occurred here `bool **arr = new bool *[5];` and here `arr[i] = new bool[5];`. BUT! If you know the values and sizes, why dynamically allocate and suffer through this hell? Why not `bool arr[5][5] = { {...}, ...};`? Faster (both in writing the code and at runtime) and a lot simpler.

Comment: Side note: To me DMA means [Direct Memory Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access), something it doesn't look like you are making use of.

Comment: There's something you need to learn here when it comes to C++: There's a difference between *assignment* (what you're doing) and *initialization* (which you do when you define the `arr` variable itself).

Comment: @user4581301 That's what I thought of when writing my comment. Otherwise I would have suggested `std::array` or `std::vector` myself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I couldn't figure out what good a pointer-to-pointer 2D DMA array would be, so I went with "I'm reading this wrong" and the simpler solution. It's a bit worse than that for me. I've been regularly using C++11 since around 2015 and I still tend to find myself falling back on raw arrays rather than using `std:array` more often than I probably should.

Answer (score 1):

If your array sizes are known statically, at compile time, you can use `std::array<T, N>`:

```
#include <array>

std::array<std::array<bool, 5>, 5> arr = {{
    {false,true,false,true,true},
    {false,true,false,true,true},
    {false,true,false,true,true},
    {false,true,false,true,true},
    {false,true,false,true,true}
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
arr[5][5] = {
    {false,true,false,true,true},
    {false,true,false,true,true},
    {false,true,false,true,true},
    {false,true,false,true,true},
    {false,true,false,true,true},

                };
```

you are trying to assign a non-existent object (the valid range of indices for the both dimensions of the array is `[0, 5)`) of the type `bool` with an initializer list that contains more than one initializers.

So this statement must be removed.

Instead you could write in the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new bool[5] {false,true,false,true,true}; 
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 5;

    bool **arr = new bool *[N]; //rows
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        arr[i] = new bool[N] {false,true,false,true,true};
    }

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    for (  size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        delete [] arr[i];
    }
    delete [] arr;
}
```

The program output is

```
false true false true true 
false true false true true 
false true false true true 
false true false true true 
false true false true true
```

Another approach is to allocate initially a two-dimensional array.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 5;

    bool ( *arr )[N] = new bool [N][N]
    {
        {false,true,false,true,true},
        {false,true,false,true,true},
        {false,true,false,true,true},
        {false,true,false,true,true},
        {false,true,false,true,true}
    };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    for (  size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    delete [] arr;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
false true false true true 
false true false true true 
false true false true true 
false true false true true 
false true false true true
```

Pay attention to that instead of manually allocating arrays you could use standard container `std::vector<std::vector<bool>>`.

Here is one more demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> arr =
    {
        {false,true,false,true,true},
        {false,true,false,true,true},
        {false,true,false,true,true},
        {false,true,false,true,true},
        {false,true,false,true,true}
    };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    for (  const auto &row : arr )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Again the output is

```
false true false true true 
false true false true true 
false true false true true 
false true false true true 
false true false true true
```

Comment: what if i want to store different rows element

Comment: for ex, second array might include all falses and then all trues

Comment: @SyedaRabiaHashmi See my updated post.